# Could not convert string to float - Reading from the fil

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file like this

```
Coffee 1
18.0
Coffee 2
25.0
```

I wrote a program to read and print out data from the text file, and my code is like this:

```
file_coffee = open('coffee.txt','r')
description = file_coffee.readline()
while description != '':
    qty = file_coffee.readline()
    qty = qty.rstrip('\n')
    qty = float(qty)
    description = description.rstrip('\n')
    print (description)
    print (qty)
    description = file_coffee.readline()
file_coffee.close()
```

When I run the program, I encountered

```
Coffee 1
18.0
Coffee 2
25.0
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

although the next line is absolutely a convertible string. Also, I don't understand why the program still printed everything out then notified that there was a problem.
I know when I used python to put data to the coffee.txt, I also put the '\n' behind everything. So I tried stripping the '\n' from the qty variable first then use float but it still didn't work. The example in my book, however, just used: `qty = float(file_coffee.readline())` I tried that too, but it didn't work either.
It's a beginner question, and thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `try/except`, use `with` to open your files and just iterate over the file object `f`. You don't need a while loop to read a file. The iteration will stop when you reach the end of the file:

```
with open('coffee.txt', 'r') as f: # closes automatically
    for qty in f:
        try:
            qty = float(qty) # try to cast to float
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print(qty) # will either be a float or Coffee 1 etc..
```

If the floats are every second line we can skip lines using next because a file object returns it's own iterator:

```
with open('coffee.txt', 'r') as f:
    next(f)  # skip very first line
    for qty in f:
        qty = float(qty)
        next(f,"") # skips every other line
        print(qty)
```

Output:

```
18.0
25.0
```

If there file s not very large we can use `map` to map to floats and get every second element slicing `readlines`:

```
with open('coffee.txt', 'r') as f:
    floats = map(float,f.readlines()[1::2]) # start at second element and get every second element after
    print(list(floats))
[18.0, 25.0]
```

You don't need to strip to cast to float:

```
In [5]: float(" 33 ")
Out[5]: 33.0

In [6]: float(" 33 \n")
Out[6]: 33.0
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you! But I have one more question: According to my book, I don't have to strip the '\n' of the qty variable before converting it into float, but the qty variable I put in the text was: qty = str(qty) + '\n' so why was it able to turn qty into number?

Comment: float and int are quite forgiving with  whitespace and \n. You don't need to strip